# Javascript posting multiple times

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript coding that pulls a PHP file, and if it updates the database, it will echo Success: Age Updated! It works and all, But When I click it multiple times it will start to do this.. Sucsess: Age Changed! Sucsess: Age Changed! Sucsess: Age Changed! .. Here's the Javascript.

```
function UpdateAge(Age) {
    var newage = $("#NewAge").val();
    var dataString = 'newage=' + newage;
    if (newage.length < 2) {
        $('#Required').fadeIn(300);
        $('#Mask').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_age.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (updateage) {
                $("#UpdatedAge").append(updateage);
                $("#UpdatedAge").show().fadeOut(1200);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

How would I get it to just display Success: Age Updated! once, instead of it just multiplying everytime I click?
Here's the Button for the onClick

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" onClick="UpdateAge(<?php echo $age ?>)" />
```

Comment: How exactly do you call "UpdateAge"?  How do you set up the "click" event handler?

Comment: Added it to the coding, sorry about that!

Comment: onClick attribute, yuck. try to separate js from your elements

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to empty your `#UpdatedAge` Element each time.

```
function UpdateAge(Age) {
    var newage = $("#NewAge").val();
    var dataString = 'newage=' + newage;
    if (newage.length < 2) {
        $('#Required').fadeIn(300);
        $('#Mask').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_age.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (updateage) {
                $("#UpdatedAge").empty();
                $("#UpdatedAge").append(updateage);
                $("#UpdatedAge").show().fadeOut(1200);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you keep appending, change the content instead (just change `append` to `html`)

```
$("#UpdatedAge").html(updateage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use something as

```
function UpdateAge(Age) {
    var newage = $("#NewAge").val();
    var dataString = 'newage=' + newage;
    if (newage.length < 2) {
        $('#Required').fadeIn(300);
        $('#Mask').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_age.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (updateage) {
                $("#UpdatedAge").html(updateage);
                $("#UpdatedAge").show().fadeOut(1200);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As .html replaces the content of #UpdatedAge and don't append it to the content, as .append does.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't think of removing the .apend! Thank you very much, it's working! Have a nice day!

Comment: @user2321809 This happens, it's normal. Have a nice day you too! :)